# How to manipulate a particular row in Data table Javascript api

Tags: jquery, html, datatable, datatables

I am using data table javascript Api. It is very simple to use. Just create an array and pass to data table. Working fine. No issue

Example:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/css/jquery.dataTables.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">   
var dataSet = [[1,'some text1','some text1','some text1',1],[2,'some text2','some text2','some text2',0],[3,'some text3','some text3','some text3',1]];
            $('#example').dataTable( {      
                "data": dataSet,
                "columns": [
                { "title": "id" },
                { "title": "Name" },
                { "title": "Parent", "class": "center" },
                { "title": "Description" },
                { "title": "active", "class": "center","bSortable": false }
                ]
            } );
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example"></table>
        </body>
        </html>
```

So I want to set a different color to a particular row based on condition.Here we have not any control over row. How ever i am trying row call back available in data table. But it always reflect to header..

Thanks in adv for your time.

Comment: what do you mean by "disable"?

Comment: The question is a bit vague, but you could use `mRender`  to check the condition and display a disabled control in `<td>` or  use `fnRowCallback` to add a disabled css class to the column. You need to explain what you mean by 'disable'. Do you actually mean 'hide'?

Comment: @markpsmith .I am fetching record from database.I want to add a different background color to the rows whose status is not active(active column is 0) .

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use [fnRowCallback](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/callbacks#fnRowCallback) for this.

```
...   
{ "title": "active", "class": "center","bSortable": false }
],
"fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
   var status = aData[5];
   // check the status
   if(status = 'not active'){ // or whatever your status value is...
        $(nRow).addClass('row-inactive');
   }
}
```

This will add a class of `row-inactive` to the current `<tr>`.  You'll obviously need a css class like `.row-inactive td{background-color:red;}` to make it work.

Comment: Thanks markpsmith for your time..But it always reflect to header only. fnRowCallback callback is called as many time as number of records in database/array. But finally it works on header only :(

Comment: is the class being added to each row?

Comment: No Mark, class is added to table only. http://jsfiddle.net/rupakdas85/nyuv8uc6/7/

Comment: I made a mistake, sorry.  I have updated the answer and here is the corrected fiddle [https://jsfiddle.net/nyuv8uc6/8/](https://jsfiddle.net/nyuv8uc6/8/)

Comment: Feel free to mark this answer as correct - I notice you haven't done this for _any_ of your questions!